# What's the `line protocol` and `Link`?

Tags: switch, interface, switchport

When I show a switch interface information, there are `line protocol` and `Link`:

```
Switch-A(config-if)# show interface gigabitethernet 0/3 

Gi0/3 up, line protocol is up (connected)
Bridge Port Type: Customer Bridge Port

Hardware Address is 0c:c4:7a:fd:ca:1e 
MTU  1500 bytes, Full duplex, 1 Gbps,  No-Negotiation
HOL Block Prevention enabled.
Input flow-control is off,output flow-control is off

Link Up/Down Trap is enabled
```

I want to know what's them? I know one is administrator can shutdown and the other is physical connect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this particular interface, the line protocol is ethernet.

The `Link Up/Down Trap is enabled` message is telling you that the SNMP trap for when the link goes up or down, for whatever reason (admin up/down, cable inserted/disconnected, etc.), is enabled.

Comment: do you mean the `admin up/down` will cause the `Link up/down`?

Comment: when I admin down it, there will `Gi0/3 down`.

Answer (score 3):

On Cisco equipment, the physical interface can have the following states:

[image]